# is something difficult to do, or hard to do?

Tags: word-usage, difference

When do I say something is *difficult to do* or *hard to do*

Or *difficult to understand* or *hard to understand*

Thus, when do I use *difficult* and when do I use *hard*?

Answer (score 5):

Both terms are [synonyms](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/synonym), they mean the same.

According to Cambridge dictionary

[hard](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hard) adjective (DIFFICULT)

> **difficult** to understand, do, experience, or deal with

[difficult](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/difficult) adjective

> not easy or simple; **hard** to do or to understand

EDITED: Take a look below to J.R's comment and to the linked entry of the dictionary. There are additional meanings of **hard** not shared by **difficult**.

hard adjective (SOLID)

hard adjective (SEVERE)

hard adjective (ALCOHOL) - A hard drink contains a high level of alcohol

hard adjective (WATER) - Hard water contains a high level of minerals

hard adjective (WEATHER) - Used to describe a time when there is bad weather

Comment: _hard_ has an additional meaning not shared with _difficult_, i.e., being solid or firm, so I will occasionally use _difficult_ (or some other synonym) when the meaning might be unclear. For example, if we were renovating a kitchen and trying to remove tiles, instead of saying, “This floor is hard,” I might opt for, “This floor is difficult.” But 99% of the time, the words are pretty much interchangeable. There may be times where someone would want to use a more precise synonym, though, like _vexing_ or _challenging_ (for a math problem), or _strenuous_ or _exhausting_ (for physical labor).

Comment: @J.R. Good point. Made it an answer and you got my vote. :-)